# Unable to find files downloaded in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, wubi

I am using Uuntu 12.04. By Wubi.
I have faced two issues:

1) I downloaded .iso file of Ubuntu 12.04 from Mozilla and gave download path in Windows partition. But I cannot find the files downloaded. When I click on show containing folder, ot opens up the location of .iso file I gave.
I tried to look this file from Windows log in but I failed to find it.

2) I moved few folders from Ubuntu 12.04 to Windows partition. But when I logged back, I cannot find those files. Neither from Windows log in nor from Ubuntu log in.

Can some one hlp, where am I going wrong?
Ay help is appreciated.

Comment: * *
I got the files. They were put into found.001 or like this folder in my Windows folder.
Before letting me see these folder, Windows had gone through Disk check of of that drive.

Forum Moderators, Please close this thread. Thank you.